# Flow typing a global module

Tags: javascript, flowtype, flow-typed

I'm importing an npm module globally use webpack's [provide plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/) and have downloaded it's library def from [flow-typed](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed). I want to point this library definition to appropriately type my global variable. I've added an `app.js.flow` file in my application's `/flow-typed`:

```
import type _R from 'ramda';

declare var R: _R;

...other lib defs
```

But it seems like throughout my app, `R` is still untyped, as flow is telling me that all calls to `R.foo` are not type checked. My other manual lib defs are working fine. This seems to indicate I'm not typing `R` correctly. Does anyone know the correct way to do this?

Comment: Do you potentially want `import typeof * as _R from 'ramda';`?

Comment: @loganfsmyth Just tried that and doesn't seem to work

Comment: Same error, or different?

Comment: No error at at all. Flow is telling me all calls to R.whatever are uncovered and treated as `any`.

Comment: Funny enough, when I change it to `declare var R: boolean;`, I still get the same result and no errors when I expect I should.

Comment: Fancy meeting you here @BrandonM.... did you ever figure out a solution to this problem?

Comment: Nope nothing yet

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do it install flow-typed and run `flow-typed install` and it will download definitions if they exist and generic stubs for any that don’t. In flowconfig, you don’t need anything else special, it looks for flow-typed as part of libs

Comment: Yes correct, but that only covers package that are imported as modules, since flow uses the `import package from 'packageName'` to associate the lib def with the variable. But here I'm importing a package globally, so there's no way to tell flow to point that global to that specific lib def.

Comment: "These special files use the same .js extension as normal JS code, but they are placed in a directory called flow-typed in the root directory of your project. Placement in this directory tells Flow to interpret them as libdefs rather than normal JS files." - https://flow.org/en/docs/libdefs/ - this suggests its incorrect to use `.flow` as the extension.  I don't know if this resolves the global issue.  See also https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/4280